# Стоит ли для идентичных сущностей заводить уникальные таблицы в БД?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, архитектура

В проекте участвуют много сущностей: *Новость, Анонс, Фотоальбом, Мероприятие*... 
Каждая из них имеет идентичные свойства: *id, header, preview, description* и прочие.

Стоит ли для каждой сущности организовывать отдельную таблицу в Базе данных или всё же лучше сделать одну таблицу и определять сущность по отдельному полю?

Answer (score 3):

Всё таки это разные сущности, и чтобы в будущем не было проблем, я бы рекомендовал размещать их в отдельных таблицах.
Например, если у нас есть сущности "Товар" (с полями id, цена) и "Услуга" (с полями id, цена), и для них создадим только одну таблицу, то проблемы возникнут, когда мы начнём вводить дополнительные поля в виде габаритов для товара, которые не нужны услугам, или свойство "единовременная" или "по подписке" для услуги, которое не нужно товару.
Примеров можно привести много.

В вашем случае, например, у мероприятия может быть дата проведения, а у новости и фотоальбома нет. У фотоальбома кроме автора на сайте может быть ещё фотограф, или тип фотоальбома (фотоотчёт, обои для рабочего стола, жанр). 
Кроме того, у каждой из этих сущностей на сайте своё представление.